# Why does this button element have different 'click' behavior than a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, dom-events

I am modifying the UI code per our analytics teams request. All clickable elements must be either an `a` or `button`.

I've overridden the `button` and `a` styles so they do not appear to be any different. In a desktop browser they don't appear to behave differently either.

But open the chrome "device emulation" from dev tools, and you can see that the `button` and `a` elements have different behaviors. Their respective target click areas seem to be smaller, and you must directly hit the svg "X" instead of any part of the block level element.

I've tried both an `a` and `button` element. I've also recreated the issue inside of a jsfiddle.

This jsfiddle reproduces the issue (test in mobile device emulator mode in chrome) https://jsfiddle.net/8jze13t0/1/

```js
// script.js
let i = 0;
const closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.close');
const clickCount = document.querySelector('.click-count');

Array.from(closeBtns).forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  i++;
  clickCount.innerText = i;
}))


clickCount.innerText = i;
```

```css
body {
  background: darkBlue;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.close {
  margin-top: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-indent: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 20 20' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M10.4809 10.0128L19.9119 0.579492C20.0423 0.479492 20.0423 0.246029 19.9119 0.112695C19.7819 -0.020638 19.5709 -0.020638 19.4406 0.112695L10.0096 9.54564L0.578599 0.112695C0.448599 -0.020638 0.237599 -0.020638 0.107266 0.112695C-0.0227344 0.246029 -0.0227344 0.479492 0.107266 0.579492L9.53826 10.0128L0.107266 19.4457C-0.0227344 19.5794 -0.0227344 19.8128 0.107266 19.9128C0.172599 19.9795 0.257599 20.0128 0.342933 20.0128C0.428266 20.0128 0.513599 19.9795 0.578599 19.9128L10.0096 10.5128L19.4406 19.9128C19.5059 19.9795 19.5909 20.0128 19.6763 20.0128C19.7616 20.0128 19.8469 19.9795 19.9119 19.9128C20.0423 19.8128 20.0423 19.5794 19.9119 19.4457L10.4809 10.0128Z' fill='white'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  display: block;
}

button {
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Click Count:
  <span class="click-count">
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  First Example With &#96;div:&#96;
  <div class="close">
    Close me
  </div>
</p>


<p>
  Second Example With &#96;button&#96;
  <button class="close">
Close me
</button>
</p>

<p>
  Third Example With &#96;a&#96;
  <a href="#close" class="close">
Close me
</a>
</p>
```

Here is an screenshot of the issue (w/ annotations):

[image]

I expect to be able to click anywhere within the block level element within the mobile emulator and trigger the event handler.

Comment: Side note, `<p>` elements can't contain `<div>`s

Comment: It has something to do with the way you are hiding your text. Remove the text, remove text-indent and overflow, works like normal. Why put text in it if you are not going to use it

Comment: @Huangism the text is for screen readers and search engines. I can remove it in place of a `aria-label` attribute... but I'm not sure why it has a different impact on button than on div.

Comment: @CharlieHoover I thought so (screenreader) but there are other options for that, see my answer. As for why, I am not sure, mobile browser must have some kind of rule that makes it weird. Also we are on chrome dev tools, it may or may not behave the same on a real device

Answer (score 2):

Remove the text and the styles associated with it

remove these extra rules

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-indent: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
```

Also remove the text from the html, why have it if you are not going to use it

If you want the text for screenreader, you can use `aria-label="whatever"` on the element

```
<a href="whatever" aria-label="whatever label">
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I removed `text-indent: 100%;` from the `.close` items, the odd behavior in mobile went away.

What is that rule attempting to do? Could `padding-left` work better? (I assume you are trying to avoid the text laying on top of the background image X icon)

Comment: It's pretty common practice for image replacement of text. In this case the text is not visible, but should still be read by screen-readers, and search engines.

Comment: I thought that is what `aria-label` is for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute . Maybe something to consider if the `text-indent` property is producing undesirable side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to figure out the specific question.  Not sure what you want to achieve visually - although i did notice this part:

> Their respective target click areas seem to be smaller, and you must
>   directly hit the svg "X" instead of any part of the block level
>   element.

Part of this is that "a" and "button" elements are what are referred to as (by default) "inline" display elements. Maybe try adding a style definition like this:

```
a, button {
display: block;
}
```

This should allow for the a/button elements to take up more space and have more of a clickable area then just having a clickable area that is equal to the contents inside the a/button element. You might also want to set something like this if you want to force a minimum width:

```
a, button {
display: block;
min-width: 100px; 
}
```

Other then that maybe providing an example of what it looked like before - or what you want it to look/behave like? This is all also assuming you aren't using any CSS framework (vanilla CSS)?

Comment: true that - my bad

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `text-indent:100%` is causing that. Instead of doing that, you can remove it and make your text invisible with css like this `color: rgba(0,0,0,0);`. Once I made that change it seemed to make the whole surface area clickable.

If you do it that way, make sure you add `color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` to the hover state as well. Or you can just remove the text out of the html if that's an option.

Comment: Not a bad strategy... Although I'm still not sure why clicking any part of the block level element wouldn't trigger the event handler. This is a pretty common practice for replacing text with an image.

Comment: Well this is a browser specific issue, it's more about how Chrome is interpreting text-indent. As a front end developer we deal weird behaviors in various browsers all the time. It looks like if you want that area to be clickable on Chrome then you will have to do a workaround like we suggested otherwise leave it how you have it.